# know better to do...two meanings?

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Does it mean the following when you use the phrase *know better than to do...*

used to express disappointment when someone makes a mistake which they probably shouldn't have.

> You know better than to believe his lie. Imply you believe his lie; I'm disappointed.

But does it also mean you don't believe his lie?

> He can't deceive you. I trust your intelligence. You know better than to believe his lie.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idiom is "*you know better **than**...*".

The conjunction "than" is always used to introduce the second element in a comparison. So the meaning of the idiom always depends on what is being compared.

- If comparing to a past incident, then you are expressing either surprise or disappointment that the person made the mistake they did.
- If comparing to something that has not yet happened, then you are reminding the person to rely on their knowledge, and not to make a future mistake.

In your example, it would depend if the 'lie' referred to had already been told and believed. If the person had fallen for it, then you would be expressing disappointment or surprise at that. If you were warning someone that they will hear a lie from someone, then you would be coaching, or preparing them not to fall for it.